# "Наконец(,) Бог услышал их молитву." Наконец — вводное слово или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, морфология, вводные-слова, запятые

*Много лет у Исаака и Ревекки не было детей. Наконец Бог услышал их молитву.*

- Возможно ли здесь однозначно определить часть речи слова "наконец"?
- По Розенталю, как **вводное слово**, *наконец* **указывает на связь мыслей, порядок изложения (в значении "и ещё") или даёт оценку факта, с точки зрения говорящего.** Запятая зрительно просится, но вряд ли здесь выражается оценка говорящего.
- Как **наречие** слово *наконец* выступает **в значении "под конец", "напоследок", "после всего", "в результате всего", "после затраченных усилий".** Но и это не совсем подходит. Если бы было так: *Много лет у Исаака и Ревекки не было детей, и они молились каждый день о даровании им ребёнка. Наконец Бог услышал их молитву.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Наконец Бог услышал их молитву.**

Это наречие, оно имеет реальное временное значение.

В значении вводного слова "наконец" или **последний довод (или тема)** при перечислении  (во-первых, во-вторых, наконец), или выражение **нетерпения, недовольства** (перестань, наконец, шуметь!)

Сравнить: **Наконец** это соглашение было достигнуто. **Наконец,** было достигнуто еще одно важное соглашение по следующему вопросу...

Answer (score 3):

Словарь "Трудности русской пунктуации...", O.A. Остроумова, О.Д. Фрамполь, говорит следующее:

**Наконец**, наречие.

...

3. Невводное, употребляется в функции обстоятельства времени в значении «в конце чего-либо длившегося», не обособляется: *Наконец я перебрался через это болото 
   (А.Куприн)* (перебирался, перебирался — и перебрался);

Такой способ проверки здесь хорошо подходит, следовательно, *наконец* в данном случае употреблено в функции обстоятельства времени.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, здесь наречие в смысле "после всего" или "после затраченных усилий".  Ждали, ждали ребенка — и наконец дождались. Молились, молились — и наконец Бог услышал их молитву.

Как вводное слово, *наконец* имело бы тут критический смысл: ну вот, наконец, услышал, и чего было так долго тянуть!