# Как четко определить функцию слова «наконец»

Tags: пунктуация

У меня всегда возникает вопрос: выделять ли слово «наконец» запятыми. Я понимаю, что если оно вводное, то выделять, если нет, то не выделять. Но мне нужен четкий критерий,  может, какое‐то слово для определения, чем оно является в предложении. Если у кого есть свои секреты, поделитесь, пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: ["Наконец(,) Бог услышал их молитву." Наконец — вводное слово или нет?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437112/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%86-%d0%91%d0%be%d0%b3-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%8b%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83-%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%86-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82)

Comment: Пользуйтесь Поиском по сайту для нахождения чётких ответов.

Comment: Проблема не в дублировании другого вопроса, а в том, что он поставлен слишком широко, обо "всех случаях жизни" слова. Нет проблемного примера.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Когда слово "наконец" является вводным?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2788/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%86-%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc)

Answer (score 2):

Сначала обратимся к толковому словарю Ефремовой:

> наконец
>
> *нареч.*
>
> 1. В конце всего, после всего, напоследок.
> 2. Употр. как вводное слово, соответствуя по значению сл.: и ещё, кроме всего.
> 3. Употр. как вводное слово при выражении недовольства, нетерпения.

Могу ошибаться, но думаю, что заменить **наконец** на **наконец-то** можно только при первом значении.

Comment: Ошибаетесь,  "наконец-то" может выражать недовольство.

Comment: "Наконец-то"  может быть восклицанием, выражающим недовольство, а вот "наконец"  в значении "наконец-то" именно наречие в значении  "под конец ожидания", "в конце всего":  Наконец я пришёл домой (Наконец-то я пришёл домой - так долго ждал этого и под конец ожидания пришёл). Уйди же ты, наконец.  - недовольство, здесь нельзя сказать" Уйди же ты, наконец-то"

Answer (score 1):

Ошибки при оформлении предложений со словом ***наконец*** встречаются часто, поэтому тема эта актуальна.

**ТЕОРИЯ**

Слово **наконец** может быть вводным в двух своих значениях: 1) выражение чувства нетерпения, досады; 2) оформление речи при перечислении нескольких тем, доводов, это такой "маркер", который завершает перечисление этих тем.

Слово ***наконец*** является **наречием и не обособляется**, если относится к реальным событиям и обозначает, что ожидаемое событие совершилось (можно заменить синонимом наконец-то).

**ПРАКТИКА**

**Вводное слово**

Да оставь ты меня, **наконец!**

Сядьте у камина, перечтите что-нибудь легкое, выпейте, **наконец**, вина.

Но: Допейте **наконец** свое вино.

Найти гитариста, бас-гитариста, ударника, клавишника и, **наконец**, солиста, того, кто будет всё это петь. [Запись LiveJournal (2004)]

**И наконец**, я не могу не отметить Ваши принципиальные позиции по борьбе с терроризмом. [С. В. Лавров. 2004]

**Наречие**

Добрая Прасковья Петровна радовалась, что дочь ее **наконец** нашла себе достойного жениха. А. Пушкин, Метель.

**ОШИБКИ (из Нацкорпуса)**

Посылаю, **наконец,** начало нашего совместного сочинения…― писал ему Адамович. [Вадим Крейд. Георгий Иванов в Йере // «Звезда», 2003]

**Наконец,** она заговорила по-немецки, как чеховская Шарлотта, о тоске одиночества, о безотцовщине.

**Наконец**, началась процедура голосования.

**СЛОЖНЫЙ СЛУЧАЙ** (зависит от контекста)

**И наконец**, в 1998 году Луазо первым из французских рестораторов выводит своё предприятие на биржу. [Эльмар Гусейнов. Чисто французское самоубийство. 2003.02.25]

Если перечисляются достижения Луазо, то это вводное слово. Если нет и речь идет об ожидаемом событии, то это наречие.

Comment: "Наконец-то" не подходит на роль определителя,  может выражать раздражение.

Comment: Мне нужен синоним, которым можно заменить это слово хотя бы в одном значении и сказать: да, это наречие или вводное..

Comment: Синонима нет, можете даже не искать и счастья своего не пытать. Мой "секрет", а именно ЭЛЕМЕНТАРНЫЙ метод анализа, который  позволяет БЫСТРО И ПРАКТИЧЕСКИ БЕЗОШИБОЧНО определять функцию слова, работающий почти на уровне интуиции, Вам почему-то не подошёл.  Ну да ладно,  может быть, другим пригодится.

Comment: *Допейте наконец свое вино.* Почему нет запятой?

Comment: Вообще говоря, здесь возможны. два варианта. При выражения чувства нетерпения делается обособление, а  если это вежливая просьба, то нет.